# WordPress Post Excerpt Class

Tags: wordpress

I'm customizing a WordPress Theme and I am stuck in adding a custom class to the `the_excerpt()`.

I have searched on the web for this function, but nothing is specific to add a custom class.

I've tried the `get_the_excerpt()`, but this one doesn't work (returns nothing).

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 15):

```
<?php echo  get_the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Shows the excerpt

```
<p class="your-class"><?php echo  get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
```

Shows the excerpt in a div with a class

Comment: Doesn't work. The the_excerpt appear with a <p> without class. Note: I've tried this way :D

Comment: If you find the corrected code useful would you mind to mark my answer as accepted? Thanks mate

Comment: Link to the relevant documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Comment: Ok, it works. Note that it uses "get_the_excerpt()", not "the_excerpt()".

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm concern wordpress doesnt provide a solution for this however you can try printing the excerpt using this solutions:

**Solution 1:** printing the class in the page.

```
<?php  echo '<p class="yourclass">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>' ?>;
```

[Link of where i found answer 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/add-class-or-id-to-any-wordpress-function)

**Solution 2:** override excert function:

You can override the excerpt function in wordpress functions.php using the following code and pasting in the same file:

```
function my_custom_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
           $post_excerpt = '<p class="yourclass">' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
           return $post_excerpt;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt', 10, 1 );
```

[Link where i found answer 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/add-class-or-id-to-any-wordpress-function)

**Conclusion:** I prefer using the solution #1 because is cleaner and very understable for someone which will maintain the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your `functions.php` to add the class `myclass` to the excerpt container:

```
add_action('the_excerpt','add_class_to_excerpt');
function add_class_to_excerpt( $excerpt ){
    return '<div class="myclass">'.$excerpt.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to put **the_excerpt()** inside a **p** tag, this is going to generate a new **p** tag contains the excerpt , all you have to do is to put **the_excerpt()** inside a **div** tag with your class name.

```html
<div class="post-sumary">
  <?php the_excerpt() ?>
</div>
```